# Why is my posted notification not being received in my Swift iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, observer-pattern

I have three custom swift classes in my app. One is a `NetworkServices` class and the other two are custom `UIViewController` classes. The NetworkServices class posts a notification to the other two classes when wifi is turned on and there is a network connection and also when wifi is turned off and there is no network connection. Currently, the app starts up posting the `isConnected` notification and code executes as expected. I then turn off wifi and `isDisconnected` is posted and code executes as expected. However, when I then turn wifi back on again the `isConnected` post is sent but it is not received by either of the two custom `UIViewController` classes. My problem is why not?

here are relevant lines of code in my `NetworkServices` class;

```
protocol NetworkServicesDelegate: AnyObject {
    func sendStockInfo(stocksInfo: [String: StockInfo])
}

final class NetworkServices {
    
    static let sharedInstance = NetworkServices()

...

    public func startMonitoring() {
        monitor.start(queue: queue)
        
        self.monitor.pathUpdateHandler = { [weak self] path in
            if path.status == .satisfied {
                // connect the socket
                self?.socket.connect()
                print("DEBUG: self?.socket.connect() called")
            } else {
                // disconnect the socket
                self?.socket.disconnect()
//                print("DEBUG: self?.socket.disconnect() called")
                self?.isConnected = false
                // post notification that socket is now disconnected
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    print("DEBUG: Notification.Name(rawValue) called")
                    let name = Notification.Name(rawValue: isDisconnectedNotificationKey)
                    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: name, object: nil)
                }
            }
        }
    }
...
    
}

extension NetworkServices: WebSocketDelegate {
    
    func didReceive(event: WebSocketEvent, client: WebSocket) {
        
        switch event {
        case .connected(_):
            self.isConnected = true
            // post notification that socket is now connected
            let name = Notification.Name(rawValue: isConnectedNotificationKey)
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: name, object: nil)
            print("DEBUG: Notification isConnected posted")

        case .disconnected(let reason, let code):
            print("DEBUG: Got disconnected reason = \(reason) code = \(code)")
            self.isConnected = false

        case .cancelled:
            print("DEBUG: cancelled.")
            // reconnect socket
            socket.connect()
            self.isConnected = true

        case .reconnectSuggested(let suggestReconnect):
            print("DEBUG: suggestReconnect = \(suggestReconnect)")
            // post notification that socket is not connected
            
        case .viabilityChanged(let viabilityChanged):
            print("DEBUG: viabilityChanged = \(viabilityChanged)")
            
        case .error(let error):
            print("DEBUG error: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
            
        case .text(let socketString):
//            print("DEBUG: .text available")
            parseJSONSocketData(socketString)
            
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the relevant lines of code from my two custom `UIViewController` classes;

```
protocol CompanyPriceListDelegate: AnyObject {
    func sendPriceHistory(_ priceHistory: PriceHistory)
}

class CompanyPriceListVC: UITableViewController {
    
...
    
    let isConnected = Notification.Name(rawValue: isConnectedNotificationKey)
    let isNotConnected = Notification.Name(rawValue: isDisconnectedNotificationKey)
        
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
...        
        createObservers()
...     
    }
    
    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }
    
    private func createObservers() {
        print("DEBUG: createObservers() called")
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(CompanyPriceListVC.dismissAndFetchStockInfo), name: isConnected, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(CompanyPriceListVC.notifyUserOnScreen(notification:)), name: isNotConnected, object: nil)
    }
    
    @objc private func fetchStockInfo() {
            NetworkServices.sharedInstance.fetchStockInfo(symbols: companyStockSymbols, delegate: self)
    }

    @objc private func notifyUserOnScreen(notification: NSNotification) {
        self.present(alertController, animated: true)
    }
    
    @objc public func dismissAndFetchStockInfo() {

        if presentedViewController == alertController {
            self.alertController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        fetchStockInfo()
    }
...
    
}

//
//  CompanyDetailsVC.swift
//  BetVictorTask
//
//  Created by Stephen Learmonth on 02/03/2022.
//

import UIKit

class CompanyDetailsVC: UIViewController {
    
...

    let isConnected = Notification.Name(rawValue: isConnectedNotificationKey)
    let isNotConnected = Notification.Name(rawValue: isDisconnectedNotificationKey)
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        configureNavigationBar()
        
        addSubViews()
        
        activateConstraints()
        
        createObservers()
        
        fetchCompanyDetails(symbol: symbol)
        
        let controller = navigationController?.viewControllers.first as! CompanyPriceListVC
        controller.delegate = self

    }
    
    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }
    
    private func createObservers() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(CompanyDetailsVC.dismissAndFetchCompanyDetails), name: isConnected, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(CompanyDetailsVC.notifyUserOnScreen(notification:)), name: isNotConnected, object: nil)
    }
    
    @objc private func dismissAndFetchCompanyDetails() {
        print("DEBUG: dismissAndFetchCompanyDetails() called")
        if presentedViewController == alertController {
            self.alertController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        
        fetchCompanyDetails(symbol: symbol)
    }

    @objc private func notifyUserOnScreen(notification: NSNotification) {
        print("DEBUG: notifyUserOnScreen(notification) called")
        self.present(alertController, animated: true)
    }
...
    
}

extension CompanyDetailsVC: CompanyPriceListDelegate {
    func sendPriceHistory(_ priceHistory: PriceHistory) {
        self.updatePrices(priceHistory)
    }
}
```

I’m testing on a real device.

Comment: What is your evidence that the notifications are not received? Have you set a breakpoint or are you simply observing that the desired action does not happen?  It is unlikely to be an issue in `NotificationCenter`.

Comment: The breakpoint isn’t hit in CompanyPriceListVC when I set at the observer selector function

Comment: Typically these problems indicate that things aren't happening in the order you expect, for example the notification is posted first, and then you start observing. Make sure to add breakpoints or print statements at the place that you add the observer, remove the observer, post the notification, and respond to the notification and make sure that each fires in the order you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Removed socket.connect() from the.cancelled case